# In a while loop of Python, shall we put the increment sentence at the end or not?

Tags: python, while-loop

I am a beginner of Python, and now learning while loop. If we want to print out all the even numbers less than 20, there will be two code examples:

---

### Code Example 1

```
i=0

while i<9:

    i=i+1

    print(i*2)
```

---

### Code Example 2

```
i=1

while i<10:

    print(i*2)

    i=i+1
```

Both seem to print out correct. However, in other programming language like C, PHP, Java, we often put the increment sentence i=i+1 or i++ at the end of the while loop.

So, in common case, which code of the above will be used most? Is there any offical instruction of Python that indicates which is better?

Thanks

Comment: Depends what you want to do with the code.

Comment: btw, you can write code on stackoverflow with correct formatting. Just select the code block and format it properly (select and ctrl+k). You don't need to write `[spaces]` to show indentation.

Comment: I don't really think this one is opinion based. the answer to "while loops with a simple counter" is "don't. Use a for loop instead with range". For complex counters, The code/logic dictates how it should go really.

Answer (score 2):

Manually incrementing a variable by one in a while loop is relatively rarely done in Python. The idiomatic approach is to use a `for` loop instead, e.g. `for i in range(1, 10):`

That said, if you *do* use a `while`, incrementing the value at the end of the block is more common. This is because it's arguably easier to recognize what the end points of your loop are. Compare the following loops:

```
seq = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]

i = 0
while i < 10:
    print(seq[i])
    i += 1

j = -1
while j < 9:
    j += 1
    print(seq[j])
```

Both of these loops print seq[0] through seq[9]. But the `j = -1` approach is a little more awkward, since at first glance you might think it involves negative indices.

Comment: And in the OP's case... it'd appear that `print(*range(2, 20, 2), sep='\n')` would probably do...

Answer (score 0):

More common use of while is with `break`

```
i = 1
while True:
    print(i**2)
    i += 1
    if i > 10:
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say for loop is better to use as you don't need to worry about the increment.

```
for i in range(10):
    print (i*2)
```